# plotly R reordering factor based on numeric variable

Tags: r, plotly

I need to reorder the x-axis categorical variable with a numeric variable so the plot is simpler to follow with plotly, in R.

Here is some dummy data:

```
   agg = structure(list(catvar = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", 
"h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o"), v1 = c(1.1, 1.3, 1, 
0.8, 1.2, 1.4, 0.7, 2.5, 0.9, 2.5, 1.7, 0.9, 1.7, 1.1, 0.9), 
    v2 = c(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0, 0.1, 0.1, 0, 0.2, 0, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 
    0.1, 0.1, 0.1), v3 = c(7.3, 8.2, 6.4, 6, 7.5, 8.4, 5.8, 12.4, 
    6.4, 13.1, 9.3, 6.2, 9.4, 7.1, 6.3)), .Names = c("catvar", 
"v1", "v2", "v3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -15L
))
```

Here is what I've been trying out. It seems recently a new feature was added to handle this but it's not working.

```
# the reordering is handled here:
ax <- list(
  type = "category",
  categoryorder = "array",
  categoryarray = agg$catvar[order(agg[['v1']])],
  showgrid = TRUE,
  showticklabels = TRUE
)

p <- plot_ly(agg, x =~catvar, 
             y =~v2, name = 'v2',
             type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines') %>%
  add_trace(y =~v1, name = 'v1') %>%
  add_trace(y =~v3, name = 'v3') %>%
  layout(
    xaxis = ax,
    hovermode = 'x+y')

p
```

All I need is to re-order the x-axis (catvar) based on any of the numeric varaibles in the `data.frame`, these are v1, v2, v3.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add to your code a command for reordering your dataset according to `v1`.

```
agg2 <- agg[order(agg[['v1']]),]

p <- plot_ly(agg2, x =~catvar, 
             y =~v2, name = 'v2',
             type = 'scatter', mode = 'points') %>%
  add_trace(y =~v1, name = 'v1') %>%
  add_trace(y =~v3, name = 'v3') %>%
  layout(
    xaxis = ax,
    hovermode = 'x+y')
p
```

[image]